# how to parallelize reads on JanusGraph with Foundation Db as storage and Es as index store

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using janusgraph with foundationDb [ ordered key value store ]. When my vertex size > 10^4 and edge size > 10^7, queries timeout after 30 secs. I want to optimize my reads which require order by eventTime [ in long ] and range() where limit of range < 500.

- Using composite/mixed index does not work after out(). Also, vertex-centric index requires data to be present in edges along with ordering. My query use case can be of any order
- Tried increasing storage.page-size to 10^4 but still many transactions are being created to fetch the data
- tinkerpop supports olap query which uses bfs and hence is parallelized. Can I use withComputer() without hfds/spark ?
- is there any other way to parallelize requests to the backend?
- is there any ways to index params so that out() based queries could be optimized?
- There is 6 instances of janusGraph and enabling caching will read to dirty leads. My business requirement requires consistent reads.

A sample query which i want to run is:

```
g.V().has("indexedProperty","Foo").and(out().has("x","00").has("y","01")).select("foo").order().by("eventTime", Order.desc).range(0,100).valueMap().toList()
```

I have mixed index on indexedProperty property.

Comment: I think there are some important parts missing in your description that could be important to understand the performance you get:
Can you confirm that `g.V().has("indexedProperty","Foo")` actually uses your index? Why is it a mixed index and not a composite index if you use exact matching? How many vertices have the same value for your `indexedProperty`? How many outgoing neighbours do these vertices have? Are they all connected by the same edge label?

Comment: IndexedProperty Uses composite indexes. I can see janus hitting es in debug logs along with profile step, Sp yes they are being used. Around 10^4 vertex have the same property.  Each vertex has 100 outgoing edges. Yes. they all are connected by the same edge Level.

Comment: A composite index shouldn't use Elasticsearch. Only mixed indices use index backends like ES. You probably want a simple composite index here as you only check for property equality.
Have you actually tried adding the `x` and `y` properties to the edges and then using a vertex-centric index? I would expect a big performance impact with that.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I am using mixed index. Also in my case, a vertex is related to more than 1000 vertices. Any my query pattern can use multiple properties. using a vertex-centric index would lead to a lot of data duplication.